# Карточная терминология: пика мизера?

Tags: лексика, терминология

> Ни один из моих приятелей не гнушался ободрать меня как липку. И
>   только **он улыбался мне на пике мизера** и говорил: «Ты ведь не
>   пойдешь сейчас с этой карты, правда?»

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, не терминология. Судя по всему, имеется в виду "пик мизера" (*решающий момент* или что-то вроде этого, лучше уточнить у автора). В любом случае это выражение не читается легко — сначала мучительно перебираешь все возможные варианты с карточными "пиками", только потом понимаешь, что это не из этой серии и начинаешь искать другие варианты.

А "мизер" — карточный термин, конечно.